# A key distinct from any legal possibilities in the data

Tags: python, naming

> "There are only two hard problems in Computer Science:    cache
>   invalidation and naming things."
>
> -- Phil Karlton

When needing some logic like below, I'm struggling to come up with a sensible name for the `THING`:

```
THING = object()

def do_something(my_dict, my_key=THING):
    if my_key is not THING:
        # some code which accesses the dict
        my_dict[my_key]
    else:
        # some code which handles this case
```

Here we can not use `None` as a default because it is a possible data value.  I'm sure this is a well known trick, so is there a well-known name for an object which does the job of the `THING`?  What's a more sensible name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sentinel` is the usual name for this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value

Comment: Except when your dictionary is storing XMen characters, then you'll have to think of some other name.

Comment: tahnks, I had thought sentinel was used as a flag for exiting a loop